# Releasing Xamarin iOS App on Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin.ios, release

When I am trying to release iOS App from Visual Studio. I keep getting this failure

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       /Users/uc/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/NexaLabIOSApp/a7eb932ce124a373359a36ab8d9e7fee/bin/iPhone/Release/NexaLabIOSApp.app/Frameworks/IQKeyboardManager.framework/**IQKeyboardManager: errSecInternalComponent**  NexaLab IOS App

Comment: Could you please share a more detailed log of the error? And are you seeing this while creating the Archive in Release mode?

Comment: - I am using the Release-iPhone mode
- Link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows")

Comment: Can u try to build it on a device and simulator in the release mode?

Comment: I did that and Build on "simulator" via "release" is working properly.

Comment: could you please share a longer error log?

Comment: @Saamer 
Thanks!, i found the problem. The thing is that, i am using a mac-agent remotely connected and while i am trying to build the Release-iPhone, on the mac side it was asking me for password. I didn't see that, because i  was compeletely concentrating on the VS side. Anyways, now the problem is solved and thanks for your suggesstions and comments

Comment: Wow that's crazy. Did you not get any sort of log on your computer about authentication? I'm glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Funny :) though sometimes we think of big errors and problems and we forgot to even notice to do the normal trends.

I just put the password in the Mac-agent and set it to "always allow" and now never asks me the password again